# Entity framework navigation property doesn't load the correct entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have these classes ;

```
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int AddressID { get; set; }

    public virtual Adress Adress { get; set; }
}

public class Prop
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int InfoID { get; set; }
    public virtual Info Info { get; set; }
}
```

Lets say i have 5 Prop , 5 Info and 1000 Address entities. When i navigate through like this ;

```
ObjectContext obj = new ObjectContext();
Prop pl = obj.Props.ToList();
foreach(Prop p in pl)
{
   Response.Write(p.Info.Address.ID);
   Response.Write(p.Info.AddressID);
}
```

First Response.Write writes down IDs 1 to 5. Which is the first 5 rows in the table. But it is incorrect.

Because, the second Response.Write actually writes down true ones. The ones that actually references the Address table's ID column by the foreign key i added in Info table. And they are like 56,568,12,596,22...

It seems that navigation property is loading the first rows in the table of Addresses.

I've researched a little bit, and I've found out it could be caused by the Lazy Loading function in EF. But i couldn't figure a way out of this. Can anyone help me ?